How to monitor requests sent to NGINX from gRPC client using HTTP/2?
I’m trying to monitor the number of requests sent to my NGINX server from a gRPC client. My setup is using HTTP/2 for the gRPC connections. I attempted to use the stub_status module to expose metrics like this:
server {
    listen 8081 http2;
    server_name localhost;
    location /stub_status {
        stub_status on;  # Enable the stub status module
        allow 127.0.0.1;  # Allow access from localhost
        allow <some ip>;  # Allow from specific IP (adjust as needed)
        deny all;  # Deny access from all other IPs
    }
}

However, this setup does not work when using HTTP/2. If I remove http2 from the listen directive, my Node Exporter works fine, but the gRPC client fails with an error saying that the server is not using HTTP/2.
How can I get the stub_status module working while still maintaining HTTP/2 support for gRPC? Is there an alternative way to monitor the number of requests sent to NGINX from my gRPC client?
